# Keycloak and Kerberos integration using curl SSO

Tags: authentication, single-sign-on, keycloak, kerberos, spnego

I have following setup given:

- keycloak server at https://auth.example.com
- connection with a LDAP provider configuration Kerberos options set in LDAP provider configuration
- authentication with Kerberos Tickets in browser works

As I know to use Curl with Kerberos auth it looks similar to this:

$ curl --negotiate -u : https://app.example.com/index.html

How to use Keycloak and Kerberos with curl without putting password in the CLI ? My user need to get access token in a non-interactive manner -> because they have already their Kerberos TGT (kinit)